# Syntax in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The following snippet is from some auto generated express code:

```
//Load configurations
//if test env, load example file
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    config = require('./config/config')[env],
    auth = require('./config/middlewares/authorization'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

[env] is confusing and doesn't look like valid javascript to me. How can you call a function like that?

```
require('./config/config')[env]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` is a function call. It appears to return an object. It is referencing a property of that object.

Does it make more sense if it was written as

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var req = require('./config/config');
var config = req[env];
```